# python multithreading a server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I've been working on this server in python for a bit, and it seemed to work, but I don't think that the threading works properly. Things seem to happen in a sequential order (the first client to connect gets ALL of the information before the next client begins), is this a problem with this threading interface for servers? Should I change it and how so? Here is some example code:

```
port = 8123
print port
backlog = 5
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog)
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept() 
    print "client recieved at " + address[0]
    thread.start_new_thread(serveClient, (client, address, board))
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that you should be using `threading` and not `thread`.

Comment: I actually just did some more testing and that wasn't the case. This works fine. I solved my problem by realizing that my problem wasn't actually there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use the standard Python module, check out [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins). It includes a Threading mixin, to make your server multi threaded.

An example test (from the above documentation) is this code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 0

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
    # more thread for each request
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print "Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name

    client(ip, port, "Hello World 1")
    client(ip, port, "Hello World 2")
    client(ip, port, "Hello World 3")

    server.shutdown()
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. CPython does not support parallel threads, due to the global interpreter lock.

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

If you want truly parallel processing, you need to either use the Process class or use a different Python implementation (Jython supports parallel threads, I believe IronPython does as well).

Comment: A server reading from a bunch of sockets is pretty much the definition of "multiple I/O-bound tasks".